# Javascript: How can I countdown and loop timer, convert datetime time from 23:59:59 to 00:00:00

Tags: javascript, loops, datetime, countdown, countdowntimer

I am building an e-commerce website.
And I want to create a countdown timer.

What I wanna do is to start the count down from **23:59:59** to **00:00:00**.
And once the timer ends at **00:00:00**, I want to restart the timer from **23:59:59** again.
So I have to use a loop.

Now I created count down timer which does not loop.
It starts from **2019/06/14 00:00:00**, and ends **2019/06/17 23:59:59**.
After it finishes to count down, the message is shown in the display that the campaign is ended.

app.js

```
function CountdownTimer(elm, tl, mes) {
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  }
  CountdownTimer.prototype = {
    initialize: function (elm, tl, mes) {
      this.elem = document.getElementById(elm);
      this.tl = tl;
      this.mes = mes;
    },
    countDown: function () {
      var timer = '';
      var today = new Date();
      var day = Math.floor((this.tl - today) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      var hour = Math.floor((day * 24) + ((this.tl - today) % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) / (60 * 60 * 1000));
      var min = Math.floor(((this.tl - today) % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) / (60 * 1000)) % 60;
      var sec = Math.floor(((this.tl - today) % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) / 1000) % 60 % 60;
      var milli = Math.floor(((this.tl - today) % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) / 10) % 100;
      var me = this;

      if ((this.tl - today) > 0) {
        if (hour) timer += '<span class="cdt_num">' + hour + '</span><small>hours</small>';
        timer += '<span class="cdt_num">' + this.addZero(min) + '</span><small>minutes</small><span class="cdt_num">' + this.addZero(sec) + '</span><small>seconds</small><span class="cdt_num">' + this.addZero(milli) + '</span>';
        this.elem.innerHTML = timer;
        tid = setTimeout(function () {
          me.countDown();
        }, 10);
      } else {
        this.elem.innerHTML = this.mes;
        return;
      }
    },
    addZero: function (num) {
      return ('0' + num).slice(-2);
    }
  }

  // 
  function CDT() {
    var myD = Date.now(); 
    var start = new Date('2019-06-14T00:00+09:00'); 
    var myS = start.getTime(); 
    var end = new Date('2019-06-17T23:59+09:00'); 
    var myE = end.getTime(); 


    if (myS <= myD && myE >= myD) {
      var text = '<span>Until the end</span>';
      var tl = end;
    } 
    else if (myS > myD) {
      var text = '<span>Start</span><span>from</span>';
      var tl = start;
    } 
    else {
      var text = "";
    } 

    var timer = new CountdownTimer('cdt_date', tl, '<small>ended</small>'); 
    timer.countDown();
    target = document.getElementById("cdt_txt");
    target.innerHTML = text;
  }
  window.onload = function () {
    CDT();
  }
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>timer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cdt_wrapper">
        <div class="cdt-btn">
            <div class=cdt>
                <span class="cdt_txt" id="cdt_txt"></span>
                <br>
                <span class="cdt_date" id="cdt_date"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope someone knows how to fix these codes to convert DateTime time from 23:59:59 to 00:00:00 and add a loop function.

Comment: Have a look at momen.js
If you are doing anything with dates/times in javascript, moment can make your life zo much easier

Comment: If you got this looping from 2019/06/14 to 2019/06/17 already … then why not just set the end date to some higher value?

Comment: http://www.tangleskills.com/self-repeating-countdown-timer-using-javascript/ 
 
Refer this Link hope that will help you :)

Comment: or have a look at http://countdownjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) and [moment duration format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format), these make working with dates and intervals a lot easier.

```js
// We can set endTime to whatever we want here (e.g. Midnight today )
// Use moment().endOf('day') to do this.
let endTime = moment().add(24, 'hours');

// Show time remaining now.
showTimeRemaining();

// Set a timer to update the displayed clock every 1000 milliseconds.
setInterval(showTimeRemaining, 1000);

function showTimeRemaining() {
    let timeRemaining = moment.duration(endTime.diff(moment()));
    document.getElementById("time_remain").innerHTML = "Time remaining: " + timeRemaining.format("hh:mm:ss");

    if (moment() > endTime) {
       resetTimer();
    }
}

function resetTimer() {
   console.log("Resetting timer..");
   endTime = moment().add(24, 'hours');
}
```

```html
<h4 id="time_remain">Time remaining: </h4>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/2.3.2/moment-duration-format.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I could make it !

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with moment.js

`moment().endOf('day').diff()` will get you the milliseconds untill the end of the day.

Moment has no built in functions to format duration, so we use a little trick.
`moment.utc(X).format('hh:mm:ss')` will create a new moment at timestamp X milliseconds that we can format using the format() function.

```js
setInterval(function(){
const timeString = moment.utc(moment().endOf('day').diff()).format('HH:mm:ss')
document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = timeString;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I could make it !

Comment: @YoheiUmezu Please post your solution, and mark it as the correct answer to your question. Or, if you used one of the answers posted to your question, mark that one as answered. 
That way people that might have the same question in the future can see how you got your problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The `hh:mm:ss` portion of a date can be retrieved from it's ISO string representation :

```js
var end = Date.now() + 3000;

setInterval(function tick() {
  document.body.textContent = new Date(Date.now() - end).toJSON().slice(11, 19) 
}, 1000)
```